# Preloader Switcher Redux Wordpress Framework

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I need to make a switch for the preloader. I created the corresponding item in the `config.php`:

```
            array(
              'id'    => 'page_load_transition',
              'type'    => 'switch',
              'title'   => __( 'Page Load Transition', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
              'desc'    => __( 'Page load transition animation.', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
              'default' => 1,
              'on'    => 'Enable',
              'off'   => 'Disable'
            ),
```

Also I have a div with a preloader html code:

```
<div id="preloader"><span id="spinner"></span></div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
var $preloader = $('#preloader').delay(700).fadeOut('slow').find('#spinner').fadeOut('slow'),
```

Now I need to make a switch, but all my attempts did not work.
I need to learn how to implement this **correctly**.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

```
if(esc_html($varuna_option['page_load_transition'] == '1')) { 
  echo '<div id="preloader"><span id="spinner"></span></div>'; 
}
```

Everything turned out to be easier.